# CMake recompilation

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

Is cmake recompiles the whole project source code if I changesd a name of directory of source files?

P.S. I tried that and unfortunately QtCreator re compiles the whole source code, is it specific to QtCreator?

Answer (score 1):

Qtcreator creates a build directory of name relative to your project or folder itself as a target build directory. so if you rename your folder name and open it with Qtcreator it will build to the new build directory of name relative to your folder name, provided you have cleaned the old source. otherwise it will take up previously generated moc files and .o files.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English in the question, I mean that I changed a single directory of files inside my base source code directory, not changing the whole source code directory, again sorry for my English :(

Comment: If you change such directory. Qtcreator doesn't re-compile the whole source. It will only compile and regenerate your added/replaced-source-dependent files. for ex: if you remove/replace a header file. It has to change the .pro file in-roder to reflect the change.like that.